# Can i have more than one 1s in the target one hot encoded vector in categorical cross entropy?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

If I prepared target labels as eg:[0,0,1,0,1] which contains number 1 more than once. will the categorical cross entropy work fine or is there a good way to do this? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have, it would be a multi-label classification

The cross-entropy would calculate something like this for  [0,0,1,0,1]

```
loss = -[0*log(p0)+0*log(p1)+1*log(p2)+0*log(p3)+1*log(p4)]
```